# How to track traffic in Google Analytics for embed codes

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, google-analytics

I have website in Laravel. We have already added Google Analytics code to it.

We have another website in Wordpress, trough URL parameters we show certain shortcods in the Wordpress template. Both Wordpress and Laravel sites are in different server and domains.

For this we are getting content from Laravel using CURL. Now we need to track traffic from the Wordpress site.

Let's say for example, there is one page called accounting in Laravel site so we need to track the numbers of users who directly visits this page. Or the number of users who visited Wordpress page who shows content from accounting page of the Laravel site.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a $_GET parameter to url of your Laravel link.

Then once someone hits the route via wordpress you can check if get parameter exists and make database record for tracking.
If someone hit the route without $_GET parameter, that would mean that link was not visited through this Wordpress site.